# Отправка формы по ajax при изменении поля

Tags: javascript, ajax

При изменении поля формы нужно отправлять данные обработчику. Написал код, но не работает. Как исправить?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function SendForm() {
$.ajax({
 var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
 
   url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'name1' : name1},
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        if(response){
            $('#res').html(response); 
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
```

```html
<form id="test_form" action="index.php" method="post">
    Имя: <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" onchange="SendForm()" />
</form>
<br />



<div id="res">123<div>
```

Comment: Ошибки какие-то есть? Я вот вижу, что у вас `var name = ...` должно быть на 2 строчки выше.

Comment: Перенёс на 2 строчки выше, заработало, но поле name1 передаётся с пустым значением в обработчик. Как поправить?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/daa2zcgu/ - ваш пофикшенный код, всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, всё работает. Единственный вопрос, форма отправляется только после того как убираем фокус с инпута. Можно сделать, чтобы при изменении поля форма отправлялась сразу?